# Adding a gauge affects the transistor switch circuit

Tags: sensor, thermistor, gauge

Thanks to the help of this community I was able to build the following transistor switch circuit (details [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/667432/beginner-transistor-switch-circuit-component-selection), big thanks to @mathkeepsmebusy):

[image: Transistor switch circuit with a logic inverter]

The circuit works and the LED illuminates based on the temperature of the thermistor.

Next I need to add a gauge to show the temperature of the thermistor. I'm using a [marine gauge from VDO](https://www.vdo-instruments.com/product/120c-water-temperature-gauge-use-with-vdo-sender-12v-250-spade-connection/), wiring diagram here for reference:

[image: VDO temperature gauge wiring diagram]

My thermistor is single-terminal with the body connected to ground as shown on the "Standard ground" diagram on the image.

I tested the gauge by connecting the signal wire to ground through a resistor, and the gauge shows the correct temperature reading.

When I connect the signal wire to my circuit above at the test point \$TP\$, the circuit stops working and the gauge reading is incorrect compared to the resistance the thermistor is showing.

According to my understanding the gauge is an active component, and its signal wire will  will mess up the voltage where it is connected to the base of the first transistor.

What should I do to "isolate" the gauge from the circuit (or vice versa) so that the gauge reading is correct and the switch circuit correctly illuminates the LED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the gauge wiring diagram, and the little information I can find about the VDO standard online, all these VDO sensors are just resistors whose resistance varies between a few Ohms to a few hundred Ohms.

There is circuitry inside the gauge to "measure" that resistance, and show an appropriate corresponding temperature/pressure value on the display. The gauge requires a +12V supply and ground, for power, and the sensor is connected between the "S" terminal and ground.

Unfortunately, your circuit completely messes up the currents and voltages that the the gauge expects to "see" at its "S" terminal. Both the 1kΩ resistor and the left transistor cause currents that shouldn't be there, and the voltage across the sensor is constrained to be always less than 0.7V by the transistor. There is no way this sensor and gauge combination can work when you've interfered so destructively with the conditions the gauge is trying to setup for itself.

If you wish for the gauge to continue working, anything you do with the S terminal must be *very* gentle. You can't sink or source any significant current from/to that node, and you certainly can't impose constraints on what potential can appear there.

I can think of two approaches that you might take to achieve this. You could emulate the sensor's resistance, so that the gauge has no idea it isn't "talking" to a real sensor. This is difficult, but possible.

An easier approach would be to let the gauge do what it does, connected in the proper manner to the real sensor, and measure the voltage across the sensor without the gauge even knowing that your own measurement system is there. This is not hard to do, but you must take care that whatever system you connect across the sensor does not influence currents flowing, or constrain the voltage across the sensor in any way. In other words, your own measurement system must have an input resistance which is much, much higher than the resistance of the sensor itself.

It's likely that the gauge passes a constant current through the sensor, in order to determine its resistance, and if this is the case, then your circuit can be trivial. If the gauge does anything more exotic, like pulsing current, then you're out of luck.

With a constant current through the sensor, the voltage across it will vary with temperature, which enables you to measure that voltage and respond in whatever way you want. To illuminate an LED at some threshold voltage, while having an extremely high input impedance, use a comparator like the [LM393](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm393-d.pdf):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVeF7N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The inverting (−) comparator input resistance is so high that the gauge won't even know it's there.

VR1 allows you to set any threshold voltage \$V_{REF}\$ from 0V to +12V. The 12V supply is unlikely to be stable, though, and if you want \$V_{REF}\$ to be consistent, you must use some kind of regulation, like a zener diode.

If you measure the voltage across the sensor (with the gauge connected and working) at 94°C, and find it to be 2V, you could explicitly set \$V_{REF}\$ like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZMWeJ.png)</sup>

R2 and D2 provide a +9V source, which remains steady even as the supply voltage varies. This is divided down by R3 and R4 to provide \$V_{REF}=+2V\$. Choose R4 to derive whatever voltage you measured across the sensor at the threshold temperature.

Be aware that if your power supply does vary a lot, and can exceed 32V (even momentarily), then the comparator will die. There may be a need for better supply regulation to your circuit, which is the case for any automotive or marine application.

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent explanation and solution. We will source some comparators and test this circuit.